# Child of Container Overflows BoxDecoration with rounded corners

Tags: flutter, layout, containers, overflow

[image]

I want to put the image in the container so that it does not overflow the rounded edges of the container as seen on the screenshot.

This is my code:

```
FlipCard(
          fill: Fill.fillBack,
          direction: FlipDirection.HORIZONTAL,
          speed: 400,
          front: Container(
            width: 200,
            height: 200,
            child: InteractiveViewer(
                minScale: 0.1,
                constrained: false,
                panEnabled: false,
                scaleEnabled: false,
                transformationController: controller,
                child: _tToImage(t),
              ),
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: Config.BUTTON_CLR,
              shape: BoxShape.rectangle,
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(12)),
              border: Border.all(
                width: 1,
              ),
            ),
            alignment: AlignmentDirectional(0, 0),
          ),
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the [ClipRRect](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ClipRRect-class.html).

```
ClipRRect(
  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12),
  child: _tToImage(t)
),
```